# Return exactly one string/value from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have read qns regarding return output from a function in Stack Overflow. All the post says to use echo

```
#!/bin/bash

 function myown()
   {
       echo "i dont need this in retval"

       echo "Need this alone in retVal"
   }

  retVal=$(myown)

  echo $retVal
```

o/p:
 i dont need this in retval Need this alone in retVal

expected:
 Need this alone in retVal

Is there a way to flush the previous output in echo. Or I need to parse all the echoed output to get my return value ? Is there simple way to do this ? Because I may have echos that are useful to debug and echo to return a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Echo output to stderr for debugging:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myown()
{
    echo "i dont need this in retval" >&2

    echo "Need this alone in retVal"
}

retVal=$(myown)

echo "result: $retVal"
```

When you run the script, you will see

```
i dont need this in retval
result: Need this alone in retVal
```